# Why is my gridview empty?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I set up an Sqldatasource and a Gridview:

```
        <asp:SqlDataSource ID="DetailsSQLDataSource" runat="server"  ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:aspnet-WebApplication6-20131007103938ConnectionString1 %>" 
    SelectCommand="SELECT [ProjectID], [ProjectName], [CreatorID], [Deadline] FROM [tProject] WHERE 1=1"
    >   
       <SelectParameters>
         <asp:Parameter Type="String" Name="ProjectID"></asp:Parameter>
       </SelectParameters>
    </asp:SqlDataSource>


<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" DataSourceID="DetailsSQLDataSource" AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataKeyNames="ProjectID" OnRowUpdated="GridView1_RowUpdated" OnRowUpdating="GridView1_RowUpdating">
    <Columns>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="ProjectID" HeaderText="ProjectID" ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="ProjectID"></asp:BoundField>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="ProjectName" HeaderText="ProjectName" SortExpression="ProjectName"></asp:BoundField>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="CreatorID" HeaderText="CreatorID" SortExpression="CreatorID"></asp:BoundField>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Deadline" HeaderText="Deadline" SortExpression="Deadline"></asp:BoundField>
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

I have tested the selectcommand, and it returns a table with 4 rows. Yet there is no data to show in the gridview. The codebehind is almost empty and surely doesn't affect these controls. Can it be something with the connection? How can I test that?

Comment: As karl suggested, call Gridview1.DataBind() in your page load event. Like this if(!IsPostback)GridView1.DataBind();

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Call `.DataBind()` to actually force the data to be bound to the grid, like this:

```
GridView1.DataBind();
```

Comment: Thanks, this works. I don't understand it though. On another, very similar page I didn't have to manually call databind, it happened automatically.

Comment: @ViktorPless - did you use `AutoGenerateColumns="True"` on the other page?

Comment: I tried both values so it probably wasn't the cause. You know what is interesting? Now that I have done what you said I don't need that codebehind anymore, newly inserted controls now function correctly without the databind method! It's like he learned how to bind the data :)